# Cocktail of chemical compounds robustly promoting cell reprogramming protects liver against acute injury

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

I would like to edit this journal article title to make it sound better

Which one is the best option?

Cocktail of chemical compounds **which** robustly **promotes** cell reprogramming protects liver against acute injury

or

Cocktail of chemical compounds **that** robustly **promotes** cell reprogramming protects liver against acute injury

Also, do I use '**promote**' or '**promotes**'?

Comment: This is a question about the jargon used by that journal.  Not really a question about English.

Comment: Use promotes if it is the cocktail that affects cell reprogramming, but use promote if it is the individual chemicals.

Comment: I'd protect *the* liver, not liver.

Comment: Among other things, the sentence lacks proper punctuation.